# How to Boolean the intersection of 2 different meshes in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to Build a set-up in geometry nodes that will allow me to use an object to control a Boolean intersection operation like below:
[image]

But I seem to only be able to get the solidified result of the two objects whereas I only want the outside faces, I've tried to merge the connected vertices and then delete them based on mesh island but doesn't seem to work... would anyone know the best methodology for doing this? or how best to select connected mesh islands?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this node setup helps you?

[image]

i just compare the distance to the original face objects and this shouldn't be too far.