# Geometry Node, Projecting Mesh Intersection as Faces on another Mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

all

working on some sort easier solution for applying stains on my models... main idea is applying  mesh intersection of this default colored grey bloob on surface of my model, to get some nice stains all around.

[image]

End result should look like something this (know it's shity but was added by knife tool...)

[image]

Was trying to use some geometry nodes pattern find on this forum here --> [How to Boolean the intersection of 2 different meshes in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301190/how-to-boolean-the-intersection-of-2-different-meshes-in-geometry-nodes) Getting "**some**" results...
[image]

but end effect is so far shity asf... multiple face in same place etc...
[image]

Can someone help in making it better?

[image]

Comment: a mesh boolean seems to be a terrible way to add a stain because it adds a hell lot of geometry to a model for a purpose that is typically done with a texture. Some possibly related answers of mine: [How to use the contact area between the instance and the mother object as texture coordinate in shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/296292/60486) and [Intersecting surface area between two three-dimensional meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/297616/60486)